# How to change "while" loop to a "foreach" loop

Tags: php

I would like to ask a question about "foreach loop" in PHP. Towards the bottom of the code below, the "while" loop accesses elements from an array individually. How can I rewrite the BODY of the while loop using a "foreach" loop?

```
  <?php
  require_once('MDB2.php');
  $db = MDB2::connect("mysql://mk:mk@shark.company.com/mk");
  if(PEAR::iserror($db)) die($db->getMessage());
  $sql = "SELECT courses.ID,courses.Name,staff.Name
  FROM courses,staff
  WHERE courses.Coordinator=staff.id
  and courses.ID = \"$course\"";
  $q = $db->query($sql);
  if(PEAR::iserror($q)) die($q->getMessage());
  while($row = $q->fetchRow()){
  echo "<tr><td>$row[0]</td>\n";
  echo "<td>$row[1]</td>\n";
  echo "<td>$row[2]</td></tr>\n";
  }
  }
  ?>
 </table>
 </body></html>
```

Comment: The code has more end braces than start braces...? Could you please indent it so it makes sense to read?

Comment: `foreach` is using to iteration whole collection, so you must get all rows e.g. `fetchAll()`, assign to variable an iterate.

Comment: Tutorial on how to use foreach: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Why do you need to change it to a foreach? As Pior says, you need to obtain all the rows into an array before you can iterate using a foreach. The original while loop you've got is fine, unless you're going to do further operations on the items.

Comment: Big Chris -- exam question !

Comment: why are we doing your exams for you...?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
echo "<tr>";
foreach( $row as $field => $value )
{
    echo "<td> \"$value\" </td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

As [**Poitr Olaszewski**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859259/how-to-change-while-loop-to-a-foreach-loop#comment36721663_23859259) commented. You will need to fetch the whole collection to be able to itterate through using `foreach()`.

That means instead of the whole `while($row....`, you'd do something like this:

```
$data = $q->fetchAll();
foreach($data as $key => $val) {
    // do what you need to here....
}
```

**[More reading -> Documentation for fetchAll() for MDB2.php](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2/docs/latest/MDB2/MDB2_Result_Common.html#methodfetchAll)**